# CSV file to PHP array converter

Tags: php, arrays, csv, converters

I have the following (partly) code which will check the values entered in a form with the arrays (like a coupon code check).  If entered value in a form is one of those in the array people can enter the code in the form.

```
 if(!in_array($posted_value, array('DA001','DA002'))){ //
```

So I have a csv file with 80.000 codes. Is there anyway (online converter or something)  I can put all the codes in between ' ' and at a ,  so csv right now is:

```
DA001
DA002
DA003
IE302
```

I want to convert it to `'DA001´, 'DA002', 'DA003', 'IE302'`

--- This is my full code, with your code included:
I have the codes.csv in the same directory as the .php file
This is my code now, but something goes wrong since I have 500 server error.

```
add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'my_custom_validation', 10, 3);
function my_custom_validation($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value){
    if($posted_field->id == 9){ //change 25 to the ID of the field to   validate
        $codes = file("codes.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        if (!in_array($posted_value, static $codes = array_flip(...);))){  //change 001 and 002 to your allowed values
        //if it doesn't match up, add an error:
            $errors['field'. $posted_field->id] = 'Deze code is al een keer gebruikt  of bestaat niet.';
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: I think it sounds like you need a database.

Comment: I don't have a option on the specific webserver to add another database. Unfortunually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `file()` function to read a file into an array. Each line will become an array element.

```
$codes = file("codes.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
if (!in_array($posted_value, $codes)) {
    ...
}
```

However, searching an array with 80K elements will be slow. If you're doing this repeatedly in the same script, it would be a good idea to hash them, by converting it to an associative array:

```
$codes = array_flip(file("codes.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
if (!isset($codes[$posted_value])) {
    ...
}
```

The full code should be:

```
add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'my_custom_validation', 10, 3);
function my_custom_validation($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value){
    if($posted_field->id == 9){ //change 25 to the ID of the field to   validate
        static $codes;
        if (!$codes) {
            $codes = array_flip(file("codes.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
        }
        if (!isset($codes[$posted_value])){  //change 001 and 002 to your allowed values
        //if it doesn't match up, add an error:
            $errors['field'. $posted_field->id] = 'Deze code is al een keer gebruikt  of bestaat niet.';
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Let's see if  I understand you, this is the whole code:

    add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'my_custom_validation', 10, 3);
function my_custom_validation($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value){
  if($posted_field->id == 9){ 
   $codes = array_flip(file("codes.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
if (!isset($codes[$posted_value]))) { 
      //if it doesn't match up, add an error:
    $errors['field'. $posted_field->id] = 'Deze code is al een keer gebruikt of bestaat niet.';
    }
  }
  return $errors;
}



Then the source file can be everywhere on the server?

Comment: Unformatted code like that is really hard to read. Edit it into the question.

Comment: Just added it! Thanks for your support thusfar!

Comment: If you're not going to reuse `$codes` for multiple validations, there's no point in converting it to an associative array. You should only do that if you're going to use it repeatedly.

Comment: I have 80.000 codes all of them can be used once (I will force the one time use a different way) but first and foremost the form I have will need to check if the code "exists" < if not the form gives a error that the code has been used already or does not exists.

I have the CSV file but need it transformed to the 'code here', 'code here',    format. 

So then I don't need the associative array? Just the first code you posted?

Comment: Every time you call this validation function it's going to read the file, create the array, do the search, and then discard the array. So you're not getting any benefit from flipping the array, because you don't reuse it the next time. You could make it a static variable, though. `static $codes = array_flip(...);`. Then it will only do this the first time you call it, and then reuse it.

Comment: I have changed the code again (see question). But I receive a 500 server error now.

Comment: Then you must have made a syntax error. Check your server error log.

Comment: You don't put `static $codes = array_flip(...);` inside the `if` statement, you use it **instead** of the original `$codes = array_flip(...)` statement.

Comment: And I didn't mean `...` literally, I was just using that to avoid repeating all the original code in there in my comment. I assumed you were intelligent enough to recognize shorthand, and that you know how the `static` statement works in PHP.

Comment: Thank you. I´m still learning. Sorry!

I used your code, but still have a 500 error.  I checked the logs:
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'  

on line 9\n.

So that should be this line:  static $codes = array_flip(file("codes.csv", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that static variables can only be initialized with literals, not with a function call. I've updated my code to do it correctly.

Comment: So the 500 error is fixed :) 
Also the code recognizes "wrong codes", but it doesn't recognize the right codes either.  Not sure what´s going wrong.  I have the codes.csv file in the same directory as my php file, so it should recognize the csv. 

I'll check if I can find out why this happening. Thank you so much for helping me this far atleast.